# How do compression algorithms distinguish their symbols from actual file content?

Tags: algorithm, compression

I would like to know how do compression algorithms actually write their notes. Let's say "4x4x" means 4 times "4x".

What if algorithm labels repeated characters like this:

23*("text") and text that repeats is 34*("something")

How would program know this is not a label for repeated text, but an actual text. I don't know how to explain this better.

After compressing this string:

```
"Compression programs label how many times string is repeated like this: 4x("text"), this is repeated repeated repeated ."
```

You would get:

```
"Compression programs label how many times string is repeated like this: 4x("text"), this is 3x("repeated") ."
```

How will algorithm know witch one is compressed one?

Comment: It's a fine question and something many people have probably wondered about.  Compression algorithms have to encode things in such a way that every symbol -- be it an "ordinary" 8-bit byte, or a special "command" code like a repeat count -- can be *unambiguously* represented.  In particular it's no longer possible to represent a single "ordinary" 8-bit byte in "raw" form (i.e., using a single 8-bit byte), since there are only 256 possible 8-bit bytes, and you need to encode a larger alphabet: the 256 "ordinary" bytes, *plus* symbols indicating, e.g., a repeat.

Comment: For more info, I'd suggest googling "prefix code".

Comment: As a simple example, you could use a special "escape code" consisting of, e.g., all 8 bits being set to 1.  When reading, if any bit is 0 in the byte we just read, then we interpret the byte as an "ordinary" byte in the range 0-254 having the value of the input byte; otherwise (i.e., if all bits are 1) then we are in a special "escape mode" in which the following byte determines what to do.  We could for example decide that the following byte, if also set to all 1s, should be interpreted as an ordinary byte having the value 255, and that any other value should be a repetition count.

Comment: Thanks, what if file has all possible bytes ?

Comment: It should be noted that every compression algorithm will be different - there's no standard way of encoding this stuff.

Comment: I know, but still, every algorithm has to put something to mark where things get repeated or replaced.

Comment: If the input file has every byte, and we use the encoding I suggested above, then every byte having value in the range 0-254 gets encoded "as itself", and every byte having value 255 gets encoded as two consecutive bytes, both having value 255.  (This is similar to how you need to double a backslash in a C-style string literal to specify an actual backslash.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, there are 3 approaches:

1. Everything is a special symbol.  So, the text would be encoded as 1x"Compression", 1x"programs", 1x"label" and so on.
2. Escaping.  This refers to using a special character to denote a symbol.  So, `4x("text")` would be represented as `$4x("text")`, and the presence of `$` means that what follows is a special compression sequence.  Of course, for this to work, a trick is required to allow us to include `$` in normal text. The trick is very simple: `$1x("$")`.
3. Dictionaries.  The compression algorithms you have in mind are variations of the extremely simplistic "Run Length Encoding" algorithm. (Look it up.)  This algorithm is practically no good for nothing and very rarely used nowadays.  Modern compression algorithms like LZW are much more sophisticated, and they make use of dictionaries, where every input combination maps to a string of bytes to output.  A full explanation would be too long to include in an answer, but feel free to look up LZW.

Comment: Can you please check my comment on another answer ?

Comment: I read it, and sorry, but I cannot understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: "ABBBAAAAC" => A3B4AC Then shuffle characters using encoding  until you accidently get something you can compress again and repeat. You uncompress and unshuffle same amount of times you did encoding.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "shuffle characters".

Comment: ABCD => Replace A with it's position in string + 1, Replace B with it's position in string + 2 and so on. ADCB - this would be used as key. If C is third characters, then it would be 3 + 3, thats 6. So C would be replace with D since D is (6 mod 4 = 2) second character.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way this is handled is to recognize (during compression) that the original text contains a character sequence that will cause problems for decompression and to "escape" it somehow. There are many ways to do this, but the simplest for the example you posted might be to compress the text to this:

```
"Compression programs label how many times string is repeated like this: 1x("4x")("text"), this is 3x("repeated").
```

That way, the "4x" (or anything else that might look like a repeat count) is not taken for a repeat count because it has been captured as text to be repeated (albeit only once). And the text `("text")` is not prefaced by a repeat count, so it will go through the decompression phase unchanged.

Note that this particular encoding scheme has other problems (such as repeated text that itself contains a double quote mark). But all these problems can be addressed with proper escape processing.

Comment: Just a quick question, do you think it's even possible to do something like this: 1. Compress the string if you can, 2. Replace all characters with random ones (that are not actually random but are chosen by some rules.), then try to compress again if there are some repeating characters, and so on.

Comment: @AnteBlašković - Sure, that can be done, although it sounds more like encryption than compression. Note that there are limits to how far this can compress. Any compression algorithm will encounter input sequences that result in an output that is larger than the input. (For instance, `4x("text")` will "compress" to `"1x("4x")("text")`, which is larger than the input.) This is an inescapable property of compression algorithms. You could change my suggested encoding to avoid the problem for this particular sequence, but it would end up having problems for other inputs.